# makefile within non-standard directory layout

Tags: c, makefile

A very similar question, but not exact to those asked frequently; my project has the following layout (cross-platform, hence different IDEs, etc.)

```
[Project]
   |
   |--- codeblocks
   |       |- obj
   |--- src
   |--- visual_studio
```

Essentially, I'm trying to get my makefile (located in the codeblocks directory), to compile the files contained within src, and have the object files put into the obj directory.

The compilation side I can acheive with no problem, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell make to use this alternative directory as the **default** location for the *object files*; moving them afterwards I can do, but means I have to recompile the entire application each time I do a build, which defeats the object of the makefile.

Reading through the make documentation (yes, I did try first, and learnt some extra things on the way!), I came across some examples, such as 
`$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c`, but make is unable to find the rule to utilize it, and I am nowhere near experienced enough to work it out for myself :(

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some suitable hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example Makefile demonstrating how to do this.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:src/%.c=obj/%.o)

obj/%.o: src/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

target.exe: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

The directory structure and files needed by the Makefile are:

```
project/
project/Makefile
project/src/*.c
project/obj
```

I tested this on my machine and it ran correctly:

```
$ make
cc  -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c
cc -o target.exe obj/main.o
```

Comment: Perfect! Working beautifully thanks; I'm going to go over the manual again and affirm I'm getting it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU make, you can use the extended pattern rules like you describe.  You can then have a rule

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

To compile the source files.  The additional complication is that you linking rule needs to also specify $(OBJDIR) for all the object files.  You can use something like

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Alternately, you can use `VPATH` to avoid the need for $(SRCDIR) in all these places.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly I'm still getting the same error as before:    `code` (2) % make proj
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/*.o', needed by 'proj'.  Stop.
(2) % make --version
GNU Make 3.82    `code`

Comment: Make does not automatically expand globs.